# Maven: Generate different wars from different profiles

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, war

I have a web application project. This project has different maven profiles (for countries and environments) with filtered properties. I have to execute many times to obtain the different wars but I would like to get all the wars in a single maven execution.

Is this possible?

Comment: Define several executions instead of profiles.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can write scipt with all those maven commands

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear from your question, but if you simply want to "run" several profiles in one maven execution, it's as easy as

```
mvn -Pprofile1,profile2,... package
```

each with it's own WAR build execution.

Cheers,

Comment: If I execute these sentence I obtain only a war. I need a war for each profile.

Comment: Do you have a `maven-war-plugin` in each profile? We'll need more info on your POM if we are to help...

Answer (score -3):

If you need multiple wars, Place different POM's in all the directories you want and configure the basic information needed.