# how to build separate war files for glassfish and tomcat using maven3 ?

Tags: maven, tomcat, glassfish

I have a Java Web project built by Maven 3.
The requirement is to have its artifact run in multiple container types (e.g. Tomcat6, Tomcat7, Jetty8, Glassfish4, WebSphere...)

The issue is that different containers have different dependency requirements. For example, Glassfish4 does not support deploying a WAR with Jersey JARs inside, while Tomcat7 requires these JARs.

Hence I need some mechanism to define several WAR artifacts, each one with different dependencies tree. Profiles might be one way to go, but that would require several build executions, one for each type of target container.

Is it possible to have one build execution produce several WARs, each WAR having  different dependencies trees?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven: Generate different wars from different profiles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22833557/maven-generate-different-wars-from-different-profiles)

Comment: Different profiles *is* an option. However, as I wrote above, it requires several executions, hence somewhat cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the `profiles` feature.

You have a profile for each of the app servers and enable only one, and run the goal, then do the next one.

There is very comprehensive documentation on `profiles` [on the maven site](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).

Comment: Yep... see my comment above. Is it possible to achieve the same during *one* execution?